# Dependency Injection with Aggregation and inject paramters into constructor in C#

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a generic class defined where the class has a constructor which takes two parameters.

```
public class CarService<T> : ICarService<T> where T : class
    {
        private readonly IElbClient _xClient;
        private readonly string _carName;

        public CarService(IElbClient xClient, string carName)
        {
            _xClient= xClient;
            _carName= carName;
            Utils.CheckCar<T>(_xClient, _carName);
        }
```

Now, I am using this class as a property in another class like follows:

```
 public class VehicleService : IVehicleService
    {
        private CarService<CarModel> _carService;

        private IElasticClient _client;

        private readonly string _carName;

        public VehicleService(IElbClient client, CarService<CarModel> carService)
        {

            _client = client;
            _carService = carService;
        }

        public async Task ProcessCheck(DateTime executedFrom, DateTime executedTo)
        {
          var exist = _carService.GetCar(executedFrom, executedTo);
}
```

I am using the method `GetCar` from the class of CarService. Now in vehicle service, I need to pass a parameter as `carName` to be used in the `CarService`. Can anyone please help me to achieve that?

Comment: Are you shure that ``CarService`` must accept ``carName`` as constructor parameter and not as a parameter of method ``ICarService.GetCar``?

Comment: `string carName` in the ctor is probably wrong and should go into the GetCar implementation?

Comment: If `CarService<T>` delcared as generic one, why `VehicleService` ctor accepts non-generic `CarService`?

Comment: @AlexanderPowolozki: It is in the constructor because I use this `Utils.CheckCar<T>(_xClient, _carName);` inside the constructor.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski: I corrected this typo.

Comment: Are you using any framework for dependency injection (e.g. StructureMap, NDepend, Lamar etc) or are using the dependency injection that is built into .net core?

Comment: Native dependency injection in .net core

Comment: Will there be more than one car name? Your setup seems not quite intuitive; I think that you make the `VehicleService` "typed" to one `carName`. I added the .net-core tag

Comment: Yes more than one car name.

Comment: Is `CarModel` a base class from which specific CarModels are derived?

Comment: No, it is only a POCO class.

Answer (score 0):

when you register the service on the Main file, try to pass it as a parameter like that

```
                    // you should to Register 'IElbClient' before
                    builder
                    .Register
                    (t => new CarService( t.Resolve<IElbClient>(), "Mazada Car"))
                    .AsSelf()
                    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

I hope the answer been helpful